# FFMPEG command is not Working when set project's target SDK version 29(Android Q issue)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-processing

I am using the FFMPEG library to get a watermark stamp on video. It is working like charm in all versions when my project's target SDK version is 28 but when i set target sdk version 29, It gives me below exception.

E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.java.io.IOException: Cannot "/data/user/0/com.videowatermark.addtextandtimestampongalleryvideos/files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied

Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method) at java.lang.UNIXProcess.(UNIXProcess.java:133) at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141) at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029) at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:698)  at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:563)  at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)  at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)  at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

//show this error

Comment: When this error is coming? i mean on which operation?

Comment: when I select video for stamping process & than  FFMPEG command passed it gives exception.

Comment: Have you checked that you are getting video uri ? Possible problem is  of `FileProvider`. Have you defined `File Provider` in manifest?

Comment: Yes i checked,I am getting Video URI, I am facing issue with only Android Q.

Comment: There is no Official Document for it.

Comment: Android Q need Permissions to run Binary file in android thats Why now ffmpeg is not working in Android Q

Comment: Which type of permission required for android Q,I am taking read & write storage permission,there is any new permission available for android Q?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: No, There is a no update ,if you decrease your target SDK Version than its working fine. on Target SDK version 28 its working in all devices.

Comment: Did you find any solution??

Answer (score 0):

Android Api 29 and above removed execute permission for app home directory.
Apps that target Android 10 cannot invoke exec() on files within the app's home directory

[Details in the following link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission)

Unfortunately I did not find a solution to the problem.